# React Native - Invalid prop source passed to Image

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am completely new to react native dev, and I am trying to display and `<Image>`.  I keep getting this error:

> Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `source` supplied to Image`

Here is what I have:
First, there is list of all images in project defined like this:

```
export const IMAGES = {
   ScreenStart1: require('../../assets/img/app/startScreen/start1.jpg'),
}
```

This is the view which calls the image component:

```
import {IMAGES} from '../../shared/listOfImages'


import FullScreenImage from '../../components/fullScreenImage'

export default class StartScreen extends React.Component {

  render (): React$Element<*> {
    let src = IMAGES.ScreenStart1;

    return (
      <View  style={{flex: 1}}>
        <FullScreenImage src="{src}"/>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Finally the `FullScreenImage` component:

```
//this displays image in full screen
export default class FullScreenImage extends Component {

  render (): React$Element<*> {
    let src = this.props.src;
    return (
      <Image source={src} style={fullScreenImageStyle.container} resizeMode='cover'>
      </Image>

    );
  }
}
```

Please can someone help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your issue is `<FullScreenImage src="{src}"/>`, this literally passes down a string '{src}', if you want to inject a variable into a string you have to do this:

```
<FullScreenImage src={`${src}`}/>
```

But, is there a reason why you're not just doing `<FullScreenImage src={src}/>`?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it was stupid typo that I missed. `<FullScreenImage src={src}/> ` fixed it. Obviously it is time for bed :)